# Are user provided translations for user provided templates possible with the django template engine?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, translation

In my webapp, I'd like to allow users who want to deploy an instance to write their own templates. Specifically, I would like to include a template for a data protection declaration using the `include` tag and have this point to a location which users can define in their settings.
However, this would not be translatable, as all translated strings have to be in `django.po` and that file is in version control.
Is there a way to extend `django.po`, e.g. use an include statement to point it to a second, user generated translations file, similar to how I can include templates within other templates?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is possible, but you best bet is probably to use some other mechanism for translation. For example, you could create a template-tag `user_translation` and make it fetch the translation from the database or settings.